# What are the differences between the Gemini 12 and the Jupiter 2?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-1965

The original pilot for *Lost in Space*, titled "No Place to Hide", used a different ship for the Robinson family's journey.  It was called the *Gemini 12* and and, apparently, had only one deck for living space.  But the *Lost in Space* Fandom, on the [*Gemini 12* article](https://lostinspace.fandom.com/wiki/Transportation_List#Gemini_12), states:

> The Gemini 12 was the name of the Robinson's vessel in the original unaired pilot “No Place To Hide.” It was similar to the Jupiter 2 on the exterior, except for a few slight differences in the ships’ profiles. Footage of the Gemini 12 would often be used as exterior footage of the Jupiter 2 creating some inconsistencies, although it is not usually noticeable. The interior however, was filled with differences. A major one being the Gemini 12 had no lower deck. Also, several control panels were different.

This talks about the interior differences and it references the exterior ones, but it does not give us any idea of what those exterior differences are.  Apparently the two are similar enough most people won't notice the differences between them.

Is there a listing anywhere of the exterior differences between the *Gemini 12* and the *Jupiter 2*?  Are there any clear diagrams or plans (other than poor quality images of blueprints) of what the *Gemini 12* looked like internally or externally?

Answer (score 2):

On the Gemini 12, the viewport is noticeably bigger and the lower hull is noticeably shallower,  with a correspondingly wider reactor core,  giving the upper deck a more domed appearance.  No circular window next to the door.  But since the ship was seldom filmed in profile,  most viewers won't notice the differences unless they're aware of them.  On the inside,  the control panels and seats before the viewport are totally missing;  the only instruments are the 3 rectangular computers.  Oh,  no elevator (understandably) and no air-lock.  It is implied that the living quarters are at the back of the single deck.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to cite the source of the information you've provided here. If you could also add any direct quotes and/or images from your source, that'd be even better.

Comment: You have good information here, but I do want to agree with the other comment. Can you provide any source or sources for this information? Or photos (or screenshots) for comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that when the Robinson's are entering their freezing tubes, there is a depression around the astrogator in Gemini 2 which does not appear in Jupiter 2 because it was leveled up, making the floor even. The astrogator's upper part was able to move up to the ship's dome and back down to its resting position.

Answer (score 0):

### How about a 21-minute documentary about a project to restore the original model (published in June 2016)?

> When *Lost in Space* was picked up for the fall of 1965, series art director Bob Kinoshita was tasked with turning the single-story *Gemini 12* into the two-story *Jupiter II*. Retaining the design of the upper hull, Kinoshita shrunk the windows and expanded the lower half.

Comment: Could you list some of the differences from this documentary in your answer? That way if the video goes down, the answer should still remain useful.

Comment: @Adamant has a very good point.  The changes are discussed from about 7 minutes into the video, but it would be a major help if you could add in a listing of what they say in case this video goes offline at some point or the URL changes.

Comment: And if you can do that, tag me in a comment and so I can do the "official" answer selection!

Comment: Nope. I provided a relevant resource, but am not jumping through hoops for your amusement. Jeez.

Comment: It's not "jumping through hoops."  The intent of SE is to provide clear and authoritative answers to questions.  One issue that we've often encountered is an answer that provides a good link to a video or website that disappears - which means, once that happens, there is no answer.